# Restoring a system image to create a dual-boot machine

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, file-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore some files out of SystemImageBackup](https://superuser.com/questions/342233/restore-some-files-out-of-systemimagebackup)

A while back I added a new SSD to use as a boot drive. After backing up my 1 TB HDD onto an external, I wiped it and now use it as my primary storage drive. Now I've found that there is a document I need to access from before the wipe, but I'd rather not deal with backing up everything I've done since then, restoring the old system, pulling the files, then trying to return to my current configuration.

In short, how would I go about restoring the old system to a partition on my storage drive, creating a dual-boot system I could then pull the document off of? Is there any better way to go about doing this?

I had saved the document to a folder on my desktop (I should have at least copied it into My Documents), so although I am able to get to some of the old files, this is not one of them. I have 728 GB free at the moment, and that should be enough to fit my old system. If there's any way to choose what is or is not restored in the process, however, I'm sure that would eliminate any issues that may arise due to limited space in addition to speeding up the process considerably.

Comment: To restore from a file backup, see [How to explore or browse Files backed up using Windows Backup?](http://superuser.com/questions/526599/how-to-explore-or-browse-files-backed-up-using-windows-backup) To restore from a complete system image backup, see [Restore some files out of SystemImageBackup](http://superuser.com/questions/342233/restore-some-files-out-of-systemimagebackup) and [Restore Windows 7 backup on XP](http://superuser.com/questions/524805/restore-windows-7-backup-on-xp).

Comment: Ah, sure enough.  I thought that would be about browsing files not on a disc image, I was wrong.  Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out all you have to do is go into Backup and Restore, choose "Select another backup to restore from", and then you can browse the backup for the file/folder you want to restore.